# How to mark last imported *obj in blender

Tags: python, object, import, blender

The (probably not so well written) question  is: Is there any way to get object data right after it is loaded through bpy.import_scene.obj function?

I mean when i import an obj file with this function i need to make some more transformation for it. When i select an object via name 'Mesh' (default name of object after import) all those functions works for other objects named 'Mesh' in my scene. I tried to get an last object from objects list in scene but they're arranged alphabeticaly, so it didn't worked well. When i tried to change object.name and apply next functions to it, it works only for one. All earlier instances of imported object are back to default.

How to solve that problem? Is there a option to get from scene last added object? Or maybe some way to 'mark' *obj object right after it is imported before next functions are applied? Or maybe there is a way to import *obj data straight into created earlier blank object.

cheers, 
regg

PS: Working on Blender 2.63

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operators don't return data they load, but you can use tagging this way...

```py
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.tag = True

bpy.import_scene.obj(filepath="somefile.obj")

imported_objects = [obj for obj in bpy.data.objects if obj.tag is False]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw after importing things, the default tag is true for all objects (including those who already exist in the scene). So it seems like that in order to mark objects, you have to assign them a false value, and then import, and then add them to imported objects if their tag is True. No the other way around. So I'm not sure this answer is accurate.

Comment: So, if you are not true whether your answer is accurate while there is an accepted answer with clean code, what's your point?

Comment: "Clean code" as in 
1. Code that was never tested (There is an error in line 4. Just copy and paste it to a blender console to see the error.)
2. Code that was never run even without the bug (fixing the error creates an array with size 0.) That because, as I said, all objects have true value when the scene start and for objects that are newly imported. 

I guess you just assume @ideasman42 's answer is accurate because of the "wisdom of the (4) masses"... I mean, if four people upvoted this, it must be accurate right?

Comment: No, I assume that ideaman42s answer is satisfying, as the OP accepted it and found the solution through it.