# Blender Object Importer

Tags: python, object, import, blender

First I import an object file to blender, now the following :

```
full_path_to_file = os.getenv("temp") + "\\" + self.url + '.obj'
bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=full_path_to_file)

#join all before imported objects to a group (not the other objects of the scene)
```

After this I want to pair all objects which have been imported to a Group (not to join), so I can position every single one and so still have the possibility to move the single objects or do some animations with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw this question on so, which helped me alot, for solving this problem :

[How to mark last imported *obj in blender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147287/how-to-mark-last-imported-obj-in-blender)